# I want to a radio button when checked should increment count ,here count is not incrementting if i have one row

Tags: java, javascript, html, sql-server

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    /*script added for update function*/
    function nosaveUpdate()
    {
        alert("sorry you don't have access to save the update");
    }
    function noupdatefunc()
    {
        alert("sorry you don't have access to update");
    }

    function updatefunc()
    {
        //alert(updateform.temp.length);
        var count=0;
        for (var i=0; i<document.updateform.temp.length; i++) { 
            if(document.updateform.temp[i].checked==false)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                break;          
            }
        }
        if(count==0)
        {
            alert("no rows selected");
        }
        else
        {
            document.updateform.method="post"; 
            document.updateform.action="AVPNStandaloneUpdateDetails.jsp";
            document.updateform.submit();
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Radio button count is not incrementing if i have only one row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "temp" is your radio buttons list, when you have only one record - it's not really an array or a list and JavaScript can't associate a length to it, so instead of:

```
document.updateform.temp.length
```

Try using the following, which should work even if you have only one record:

```
document.getElementsByName('temp').length
```